# Order by amount of entries in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table like this `id, name, datetime` which might store multiple entries per day, now I am looking for a way to select the day with the highest amount entries in just one query.

Until now I was doing a loop through all the entries and comparing a `$highest` integer against every value, but there must an easier way to do it with one sql query. Ideas anyone?

**Update**:

The table basically looks something like this

```
id, name, datetime
1, test, 2010-12-01 12:12:12
2, test2, 2010-11-30 12:12:12
3, test3, 2010-11-30 13:13:13
4, test4, 2010-10-29 12:12:12
```

the result would need to be `2010-11-30` because there are two entries from that specific day and it is effectively the "highest day" (or day with the highest amount of entries).

Comment: The responses you have now look correct. What does "didn't work as hoped" mean?

Comment: Both scripts do not return the date with the highest amount of entries

Comment: I have created a temporary table with your 4 test rows and ran the queries from the existing answers, and they provide the result you ask for (2010-11-30).

Comment: Yep, works now, I needed to update column names accordingly, my mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATE(`datetime`) AS `date`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work as hoped, my question might have been misleading, I updated it accordingly.

Comment: This query returns `| 2010-11-30 |` which is the date with the most entries. That's what you asked for.

Comment: worked like a charm now, my mistake, I also used `datetime` label for the `date` column, which didn't work out.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id, name, DATE(`datetime`) AS `date`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM things
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

If you only want the highest day, add a `LIMIT 1` at the end.

Keep in mind that the `id` and `name` will be from a random record on that day. If you want all of the records on that particular day, you'll need to run another query or use a sub-query.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work as hoped, my question might have been misleading, I updated it accordingly.

Comment: This query returns: `| 2 | test2 | 2010-11-30 |     2 |` which is a row corresponding to the date with the most entries. That's what you asked for.